# Mapserver: "Premature end of script headers: mapserv,"

Tags: gdal, mapserver

Some of requests to the Mapserver return "Internal server error". When I checked the Apache log I saw that there are several error messages:

```
GDAL: In GDALDestroy - unloading GDAL shared library., referer: http://...
GDAL: In GDALDestroy - unloading GDAL shared library., referer: http://...
Premature end of script headers: mapserv, referer: http://...
```

I'm not familiar with the GDAL and I'm not sure how to fix the problem.

**Update**

```
Ubuntu 13.04
GDAL 1.9.0, released 2011/12/29
Mapaserver 6.2.1
POSTGIS="1.5.3" 
GEOS="3.3.8-CAPI-1.7.8"
```

The "Premature headers end" resolves in not loading some part of the map, but not the entire map. The strangest think is that when I zoom in some of the missing parts are getting shown.

**Update 2:**

Here is another error I found:

```
msProjectRect(): some points failed to reproject, doing internal sampling.
```

**Update 3:**

The main problem was in the extent set for the layer in the map file. It was not cover all the polygons which I want to render.

Comment: gdal is working on your OS?

Comment: Almost impossible to solve your issue with that information. Ideally you should make a minimal package for reproducing your issue: data, mapfile and request that leads to Internal server error, and information about the environment: MapServer and GDAL version, operating system at least.

Comment: You are right, I added information for the environment I'm working on.

Comment: what are you trying to load with gdal? that msProjectRect message refers to a known error according to this: https://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/ticket/1999 and this http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapserver-dev/2003-March/005263.html. Basically, a degenerate rectangle (whatever that means). When I use grids, I use the same grid cell size for x and y, perhaps that's your problem.

Comment: There is still far too little information. It may be that projections of data and output do not suit, for example having data from polar regions and trying to generate output into Web Mercator but it can be something else as well. Mapfiles and sample data would be of great help. If you do not want to share them add at least DEBUG 5 into your mapfile and update to MapServer 6.4 and more fresh GDAL from ubuntugis-unstable repository. PostGIS is pretty old too but 1.5 used to work fine for me. Checking data with SQL "IsValid" in never a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

The main problem was in the **extent** set for the layer in the map file. It was not cover all the polygons which I want to render.

Comment: It might be helpful to others if you could add at least some general indication of *what* the problem with the data was. If the issue is very specific to your case and isn't something you think anyone else is likely to run into, you might consider deleting the question altogether.